# Does the ending of Predestination cause a paradox, or does the loop stay closed?

Tags: plot-explanation, predestination

In the final scene of *Predestination* there's the following dialogue:

> **John**: Your next attack will kill ten thousand more.

John knows this because it is his strongest motivation for hunting down the fizzle bomber.

Later:

> **Fizzle Bomber**: You wanna know what we're gonna do tomorrow?
>
> **John**: No.
>
> (**John shoots the fizzle bomber**)

My questions:

Does the ending cause a paradox because John has supposedly stopped the fizzle bomber from executing his big plan, hence erasing the motivation for the events of the movie? If so, what indicates this?

If not, what signs indicate that the big hit takes place earlier in the fizzle bomber's life, before the laundromat encounter?

Comment: Okay, I just realized that it's possible that the fizzle bomber doesn't have to be around to trigger the bomb. Perhaps not being able to find and defuse the bomb after repeated attempts drove John into madness, and knowing what places John had looked at, the fizzle bomber knows precisely where to place the bomb so that John can't find it. Is that a reasonable theory?